# How can I resolve issue with data not populating UITableView until I redeploy app after updating?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've just setup a `UITableview` with Core Data and Grand Central Dispatch to update my app and display information through my `fetchedResultsController`.  I have the application updating my database; however, the `UITableView` only gets populated once I redeploy the application to my phone through Xcode.  For instance I run the update and everything works fine except I have an empty `UITableView`.  Then I can close the app and click "Run" again through Xcode and when the app comes up the information is in the `UITableView`.  I'm including the code below in hopes someone can help me discover why this is the case.  If I need to include more code please just let me know. Thanks!

**TeamTableViewController.m**

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController \*)fetchedResultsController {
        ...

        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchREquest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"stateCode" cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        ...
    }

    -(IBAction) refreshList:(id)sender {

       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("updateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

       dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"https://path/to/file.xml"];});
       dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"https://path/to/file2.xml"];});
       dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"https://path/to/file3.xml"];});

    }

    - (BOOL)updateFromXMLFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {

       AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

       XMLParser *parser1 = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
       XMLParser *parser2 = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
       XMLParser *parser3 = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

       BOOL success = FALSE;

       NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pathToFile];
       NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

       if ([pathToFile rangeOfString:@"people"].location != NSNotFound) {
           NSManagedObjectContext * peopleMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
           [peopleMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

           NSNotificationCenter * notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
           [notify addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object: peopleMOC];

           parser1.managedObjectContext = peopleMOC;
           [xmlParser setDelegate: parser1];
           success = [xmlParser parse];

           if (success) {
               NSError * error = nil;
               @try {
               [parser1.managedObjectContext save:&error];
               } catch (NSException * exception) {
                  // NSLog logs the exception...
               }
               [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
               Return TRUE;
           } else {
               // NSLog logs errors
               return FALSE;
           } 
    } elseif ... {  // other 3 use practically same code here }

    [appDelegate saveContext];

}
    -(void) mergeChanges:(NSNotification *) notification {

        AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[theDelegate managedObjectContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject: notification waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm able to kind of get it to work by adding `[theDelegate saveContext];` to the end of my `-(void)mergeChanges` method... This just doesn't seem like the proper way of doing it to me. Thoughts?

**UPDATE 2**

The above method worked one time but I've been unable to get it to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol to inform your view controller of any changes in the data.

Use `controllerDidChangeContent:` rather than the other methods. Like this, the results will be reflected once all the downloads have finished. Shorter incremental updates might get computationally expensive.

There is a very succinct "Typical Use" example in the [delegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I'm currently using that method. The following is contained in the method: `[self.tableView endUpdates];`